# VueComponent.mounted : TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined in mounted hook

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I am using jest for unit testing in nuxt js
I have mounted hook like this

```js
async mounted(){
  
  try{
     var response = await this.$axios.get("api_url here");
     this.result = response.data;
  } catch(e){
    console.log("Exception: ",e)
  }
}
```

when i do unit test for it my code is . utnit.spec.js

```js
jest.mock("axios", () => ({
   get: () => Promise.resolve({ data: [{ val: 1 }] })
}));


import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import file from '../filefile';
import axios from "axios";


describe('file', () => {
  test('check comp. working correctly', () => {
    var wrapper = mount(file);
    afterEach(() => {
      wrapper.destroy()
    })
  })   
})
```

I am getting this warn there and there is no data in the results

```js
Exception:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
          at VueComponent.mounted
```

how do I know what is the problem here, is this I can not access axios in the unit file Is there  any specific way to test Axios in mounted hook

Comment: You have to mock axios

Comment: I have mock axios like this     jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  get: () => Promise.resolve({ data: [{ val: 1 }] })
})); but the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that it's `this.$axios.get` that is not available, not `axios.get`. The component relies on Axios plugin that is commonly installed in Vue application entry point or Nuxt configuration.

It can be installed for `localVue` Vue instance in tests, or be supplied directly to the component:

```
var wrapper = mount(file, { mocks: { $axios: axios } });
```

Also, the mock will fail if Axios is used as `axios()` somewhere because default import is expected to be a function:

```
jest.mock("axios", () => Object.assign(
  jest.fn(),
  { get: jest.fn() }
));
```

`axios.get` is Jest spy, the implementation is mocked per test depending on the use and isn't limited to hard-coded `Promise.resolve({ data: ... })` supplied in the mock.

Comment: thanks a lot now when i do console.log(wrapper.vm.res) i got ...  [ { val: [Getter/Setter] } ]  so would you suggest me where i can read about all jest fn or brief about it

Comment: or like i can set value of promise after reslove what will i get

Comment: wrapper.vm.res is not provided in the question and isn't related to Axios problem. Console output means that res is an array of objects. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api and possibly other mock-related chapters. You need to do `axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: ... })` in-place before its expected call.

Comment: my Bad!  so wrapper.vm.result is . [ { val: [Getter/Setter] } ]  , what is mean by that . and also i have done what changes you suggest and after jest.mock("axios", () => Object.assign(
  jest.fn(),
  { get: jest.fn() }
));
 i code axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: {val :1 }) but even after that i;m not getting the  [ { val: [Getter/Setter] } ]  , so did not get how to resolve it , and thank very much for answering  would you help me out please

Comment: res is an array that was provided by the mock, this means that it was mocked correctly, and component parts that rely on it should work ok. res is transformed by Vue to make it reactive, this is the reason why it looks like that in console output. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html for how this works.

Comment: so  i change my code a bit like await axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: ... })in it/test block  and after it i did console.log(wrapper.vm.res) and got undefined value and also getting in axios request in page cannot read data of undefined how it can be possible

Comment: axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce goes before it's called, i.e. before mount. No `await` is needed there. If you need to wait for it to apply, you need to expose the promise to await, should be instead `let mockRes = Promise.resolve({ data ... }); axios.get.mockValueOnce(mockRes); var wrapper=mount(...); await mockRes`. At this point res should be applied to the component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221202/discussion-between-vipul-and-estus-flask).

Comment: no problem ..is there any other way where i can show you code , and take feedback from you what should be done exactly ,

Comment: You can add a new snippet that shows your current attempt to the question (in addition to existing ones) or show a link to Codesandbox or Stackblitz.